# How to remove an account from OpenID?

Tags: openid

I am not sure if it's not possible, or I just can't find the option. I approved a website/account on my OpenID account, but now I want to remove it from my account. Is that possible? If yes, how do I remove it? I was unable to find a way so far. The best thing I have come up with so far is setting the "Always Approve" to off for certain websites/accounts.

(I am talking about the [myopenid](https://www.myopenid.com/) website.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have answered your own question.

Ultimately, openID is unlike OAuth(think twitter) in that to log into remote sites you will have to enter credentials at the openID website to unlock your other account.  Nothing you do on the openID site will really unlink the account because the OTHER site is associated with the openID site, rather than the other way around.

If your goal is to simply use a configured username/password with the other site, rather than your openID, try removing the association from the OTHER webservice, once you have configured the username/password.

It might be useful to know WHY you want to remove authorization for a site.

Comment: I don't really remember why I wanted it removed anymore.. I think I just wanted to switch to another openid provider at that time. This does answer my question however. Thank you.